# how to get instance name in bound method?

Tags: python, django

I made an 'Club' class, and several instances. then I set student as foreign key for club. like this.

in models.py

```
class Club(models.Model):
    club = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.club

class Student(models.Model):
    student = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    clubs = models.ManyToManyField(Club, related_name='inclubs')
    class_s = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isfilled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    atclub = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student

    def atclub(self):
        return self.atclub
```

I want to get which club student involved. so I wrote,

in my results_view.html

```
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>동아리 신청 확인</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul>
        {% for student in a %}
        <div style="text-align:center">
        <li>{{student.student}}--{{student.atclub}}</li>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <a href="{% url 'club:index'%}">Go to the main</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

but the result is,

(page view)

```
(student name)--<bound method Student.atclub of <student name>>
```

I want to get club name instead of bound method. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a `atclub` field. You have a `atclub` *method*, which replaced the field:

```
atclub = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

def atclub(self):
    return self.atclub
```

The second `atclub` name replaced the first; you can't have both. Calling the `atclub` method will just return the method object itself.

Rename one or the other, or remove the method entirely (it doesn't appear to do anything of use).

Comment: then I get error 'invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(club_name)' '. How should I do?

Comment: @김예지: I don't know, that's not enough information for me to diagnose what is going on.  That looks like an unrelated error, a new problem exposed by correcting the one in your question. Perhaps ask a new question about that problem, but make sure to include a *complete traceback* for that error, not just part of the last line.

Comment: I edited question (added trackback of errorpage). Is there necessary additional information?

Comment: @김예지: See the `Switch to copy-and-paste view` text in what you posted? Please click on that in your browser, then copy the text from *there*. What you pasted now is useful only when using a browser to interact with the information directly.

Comment: is that okay now?

Comment: Yes, but it is clear you have a new, different problem; post that as a new question, and make sure you are including how you defined your student. You appear to have used `'CREATOR'` as a foreign key for the club, but your `Club` model doesn't have a string primary key, it has an automatically generated integer primary key.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define the method.

```
def atclub(self):
    return self.atclub
```

Because `atclub` is already an attribute, doing `student.atclub` will work.

Comment: then I get error 'invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(club_name)' '. How should I do?

Comment: Then post another question with the relevant code and the full traceback.

Comment: I edited question (added trackback of errorpage). Is there necessary additional information?